# Mix Compilation of MPI and CUDA with Dynamic Parallelism

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, mpi, nvcc

I ran into one compilation problem when I want to compile the MPI+CUDA mixed program with dynamic parallelism support.

Source code of dyn_pal.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#define N 100
#define M 32
#define K 2
__device__ volatile int vint = 0;
__global__ void entry( volatile int* foo ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        atomicAdd((int*)foo, 1);
    }
}

//extern "C" __global__ void diverge_cta( volatile int *foo )
extern "C" __global__ void diverge_cta( volatile int *foo )
{
  __shared__ int x;
  if ((threadIdx.x%32) != 0) {return;}
////    entry(foo);   //original design: each thread call entry()
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        entry<<<1,M>>>( foo );
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        x = 5;
        return;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    atomicAdd((int*)foo, x);
}

extern "C" void mycal(int myrank){
    int *foo; int h_foo;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&foo, sizeof(int)); cudaMemset(foo, 0, sizeof(int));
    printf("foo addr: 0x%x\n", (unsigned)(size_t)foo);
    diverge_cta<<<K,M*32>>>( foo );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(&h_foo, foo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (h_foo == K*(M*N+5*(M-1))) {
        printf("simple_scan_test test PASSED\n");
    } else {
        printf("Result: %d\n", h_foo); printf("simple_scan_test test FAILED\n");
    }
}
```

Sourcecode of MPI code: indexed_gpu.c.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
void diverge_cta( volatile int *foo);
void mycal(int myrank);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int myid, numprocs, i, j, k;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
  mycal(myid);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The compilation command I used:

- nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dc dyn_pal.cu -o dynpal.o -lcudadevrt
- mpicc -c indexed_gpu.c -o mpi_bench.o
- mpicc mpi_bench.o dynpal.o -o gpu_idx -L/opt/cuda/5.5/lib64 -lcudart

Error I got:

dynpal.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_42_tmpxft_000044ae_00000000_6_dyn_pal_cpp1_ii_vint()':
tmpxft_000044ae_00000000-3_dyn_pal.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to`__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_42_tmpxft_000044ae_00000000_6_dyn_pal_cpp1_ii_vint'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

BTW, if I didn't include '-dc' when compiling cuda object file (line 1), I got this error:

dyn_pal.cu(25): error: kernel launch from **device** or **global** functions requires separate compilation mode
1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00004303_00000000-6_dyn_pal.cpp1.ii".

If I don't use MPI programs, the pure CUDA program with parallelism support can compile and run sucessfully on my Kepler GPUs.

I am wondering, whether CUDA dynamic parallelism is supported for mixed program?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. I suspect the indexed_gpu.c source code you have posted isn't really
   what you are using.  You don't need to include cuda.h and
   cuda_runtime.h in that file, but according to my understanding of
   mpi, you do need to include mpi.h in that file.
2. With this compile command: `nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dc dyn_pal.cu -o dynpal.o -lcudadevrt` it's not necessary to provide `-lcudadevrt` switch.  That is a linker switch and you are not linking anything with this command.
3. Referring to the [nvcc documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#examples), we see that when we want to use the host linker separately for final linking of the executable, it's necessary to perform an extra device-link step, when we are using separate compilation and linking (which is required for dynamic parallelism).

With the following sequence of commands and the above changes, I was able to compile and link your code:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dc dyn_pal.cu -o dynpal.o
mpicc -c indexed_gpu.c -o mpi_bench.o
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dlink dynpal.o -o dynpal_link.o -lcudadevrt
mpicc mpi_bench.o dynpal.o dynpal_link.o -o gpu_idx -L/opt/cuda/5.5/lib64 -lcudart
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I still get the similar error. Which mpicc related library did you try? OpenMPI, Mvapich or mpich? Thanks.

Comment: I used mpich2, as a matter of convenience.  Did you look at the final compile line closely?  I am linking both `dynpal.o` and `dynpal_link.o` together.  Perhaps you should update your question with the exact console output showing your compile sequence and the error output, using the modified sequence I have shown.